# I'm unable to retrieve a list of users from the API to the client app(Angular). I am new to angular

Tags: angular, typescript, client

When I view the Network tab I one of the users is in red(color). On the console there's is an error 401(Unauthorized). Here is the code for the different files; the memberService.ts, member-list-component.ts. There us no error when it comes to compiling.

**memberService.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Member } from '../_models/member';

const htttpOptions ={
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  Authorization: 'Bearer'+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token
  })
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MembersService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getMembers()
  {
    return this.http.get<Member[]>(this.baseUrl+ 'users', htttpOptions);
  }

  getMember(username :string){
    return this.http.get<Member>(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + username, htttpOptions);
  }
  
}
```

**member-list-component.ts**

```
import { MembersService } from './../../_services/members.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Member } from 'src/app/_models/member';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-list',
  templateUrl: './member-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-list.component.css']
})
export class MemberListComponent implements OnInit {
  members: Member[];

  constructor(private MemberService: MembersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadMembers();
  }
  loadMembers()
  {
    this.MemberService.getMembers().subscribe(members=>{
      this.members = members;
    })
  }

}
```

I get it that my access is an authorized but one thing to note is that Postman returns a list of users to me as shown below.
**console tab when inspecting**
[console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoZLR.png)

**Network Tab information 1.0**
[Network Tab information 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMbac.png)

**Network Tab information 2.0**
[Network Tab information 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CksVH.png)

**PostMan returns my list of Users successfully so the API is Ok. I don't know why the client side isn't doing that as well**
[PostMan Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlOPE.png)

Comment: You're getting the 401 error that means you're unauthorized to access the resource. Please pass correct authorization token.

Comment: I wonder if you just need a space between `'Bearer'` and your token? Instead of `'Bearer' + ...`, maybe try `'Bearer ' + ...`? (Note the extra space here). Looking at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.1, it seems like the extra space is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
const htttpOptions ={
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  Authorization: 'Bearer '+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token
  })
}
```

Update your httpOptions like above.

Comment: Thanks . Why do we need a space after the 'bearer '?